# Postgres: Find matching array or array that contains t

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I'm using postgres 9.5 and have a table that looks something like this:

```
+----+--------------+-------------------------------+
| id | string_field | array_field                   |
|----+--------------+-------------------------------|
| 1  | string a     | [apple, orange, banana, pear] |
| 2  | string b     | [apple, orange, banana]       |
| 3  | string c     | [apple, orange]               |
| 4  | string d     | [apple, pear]                 |
| 5  | string e     | [orange, apple]               |
+----+--------------+-------------------------------+
```

Is it possible to query the DB for rows where `array_field` **is, or contains** `[apple, orange, banana]`? The results should return rows with id 1 and 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
where array_field @> ARRAY['apple', 'orange', 'banana']::varchar[]
```

[**Documentation**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've realized I actually have an array in a jsonb column, what would the syntax look like for that?

Comment: I've got it: `select * from tmp where jsonb_column @> '["apple", "orange", "banana"]'::jsonb;`